# duplicate rows using insert into

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table that contains data and I want to use insert into statement
here is my query

```
  INSERT INTO [table]
  SELECT Distinct * FROM [DataSource]
```

how to to ignore a row from being inserted if it's already found in the table?

Comment: you need to add some details of your db schema, context around this query and information about what you are trying to do as this looks like gibberish to me

Comment: that is my query ! my question is what to do to ignore any duplicated row?

Comment: what i'm trying to say is, that nobody is going to answer this question in this format as it's not clear what you are asking, so unless you edit it you will risk it being closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your target table and your data source table have identical structure, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [table]
SELECT Distinct * 
FROM [DataSource]
EXCEPT
SELECT * 
FROM [table]
```

Alternatively, you could use MERGE statement or SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS.